# How to get Safari crash report?

Tags: ios, crash, mobile-safari

I have been able to reproduce a bug that makes the iOS5 browser crash and stop unexpectingly. I am unable to reproduce that bug outside of our web application so I was thinking to send a crash report of when it happens within our application as a bug report. Is it possible to get a crash report of any kind for the Safari application so that I can send it as a bug report ? If it's possible, how do I do it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find it easiest to use the settings app on iOS:

- General
- About
- Diagnostics & Usage
- Diagnostics & Usage Data
- scroll to the crash you care about and tap it
- select all, copy the text

Now you can paste the report wherever you please. Email, [Simplenote](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/simplenote/id289429962?mt=8), notes, [Evernote](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/evernote/id281796108?mt=8), or wherever else you like to store the text for submitting a [bug with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com/). You can also get at the logs after syncing from iTunes or Xcode - but getting it when the crash happens works best for me in most cases.

Comment: This worked like a charm and I won't have to wait to get home to take a look at the crash report.

Comment: In iOS 10 the list of crashes can be found via Settings > Privacy > Analytics (bottom) > Analytics Data

Answer (score 2):

If you have Xcode installed, plugin your device to your computer and open Xcode. Then open the Organizer, which can be found in the Window Menu.  Now find the desired crash log (as shown below) and click the export button (bottom of window).  This gives you a .crash file that you can send to the developer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can pull crash reports from your phone using Organizer in Xcode: [Locating Crash Reports](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/debugging/locating-crash-reports.html).

It looks like iTunes also [copies them over when it syncs](http://aplus.rs/apple/how-to-find-crash-logs-for-iphone-applications-on-mac-vista-and-xp/), so you should be able to get at them from Windows if you don't have a Mac.