# How to see crash log on iPad 5.1.1

Tags: ipad, crash

How can I see crash log on original iPad?

Comment: If you have a Mac, plug it into your Mac and sync with iTunes. The logs will sync over and be viewable in the Console.app. No idea how to view logs via Windows

Comment: Do you want to look into the logs on the iPad itself or on your computer? If on computer, are you looking for an OSX or a Windows solution?

Comment: Several answered questions should cover this. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50287/how-to-get-safari-crash-report and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104988/iphone-5s-crashing-infrequently-despite-restoring